# On "def" notation

Tags: notation

I've been perplexed by the notation of writing def above an equal sign, even though it seems rather trivial. So, in the example below, is this the correct usage of def?

$f'(x) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$

Also, is this notation preferred to $:=$?

Comment: Yes it is correct and common. "Preferred" is subjective. I use $:=$ because it is easier to typeset.

Comment: The ["equality" sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_(mathematics)) has many uses (and meanings)...

Comment: See also [this post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/19773/whats-the-difference-among-the-logical-relations-and-%e2%89%a1)

Comment: (You may also see $\overset{def}{\iff}$ used similarly.)